# Refreshing Google API credentials throws TypeError after working several times in Python

Tags: python, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to authenticate and send an email using the **Gmail API** in **Python**. I've set up a function to handle the authentication. It worked well for several times, but then I started encountering an issue when trying to refresh the credentials:

```
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import os

CREDENTIALS_FILE_NAME = 'credentials.json'
TOKEN_NAME = 'gmail_token.json'

def authenticate(self) -> Any:
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists(self.TOKEN_NAME):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(self.TOKEN_NAME, self.get_scopes())
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())  # <-- This line causes the error
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(os.path.join(Project.root_path(), self.CREDENTIALS_FILE_NAME), self.get_scopes())
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open(self.TOKEN_NAME, 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
    return build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

def get_scopes(self) -> list:
        return ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send']
```

After successfully authenticating and sending emails multiple times, I now get the following _*error*:

```
creds.refresh(Request())
                  ^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: Request.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
```

Can anyone help me fix this error or provide a detailed explanation of why it's occurring?

**Edit**

After `print(creds.token_uri)`

This `url` received:
`https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`

So I try this:
`credentials.refresh(Request(url=credentials.token_uri))`

And got `TypeError: 'Request' object is not callable`

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a wild guess and say it worked for a week.  Your refresh token has probably expired and your code is not taking into account any errors if the refresh token refresh throws an error.  Try this if the refresh token fails to refresh it will deleted your stored tokens and prompt the user to authorize the application again.

```
"""Shows basic usage of the Gmail v1 API.
    Prints a list of user messages.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        try:
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
            creds.refresh(Request())
        except google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError as error:
            # if refresh token fails, reset creds to none.
            creds = None
            print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'C:\YouTube\dev\credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
```

Comment: the true is that this working 2-3 hours, BTW this is not the case with Google Calendar (until now it 2-3 days that this working)

Answer (score 0):

The `Credentials` class [has](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/google.oauth2.credentials.html#google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials) a `token_uri` parameter, which **must** be specified in order for refresh to work:

> token_uri (str) – The OAuth 2.0 authorization server’s token endpoint URI. Must be specified for refresh, can be left as None if the token can not be refreshed.

By default `token_uri` is `None`, and, since you're creating a `Credentials` instance using a classmethod `from_authorized_user_file()`, it's not specified.

That's why, when a `Request` instance is called to make a refresh call, it errors out with `Request.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'`; no refresh url is found in the `Credentials` instance.

I'm not sure why `refresh()` does not throw exception earlier, since it [seems to check](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/2503d4a50995d4f2756846a17b33997273ace5f1/google/oauth2/credentials.py#L326) whether the `self.token_uri` is `None`, but it may have been added in some later version of the library, while you're using an earlier one.

To verify, whether this is really the reason for your problem, `print(creds.token_uri)`. If it's `None`, it won't work.

To fix it, create the `Credentials` instance with the main constructor, and provide the `token_uri`.

Comment: Can i have cod example ?

Comment: Code example on how to initialize a `Credentials` instance? Have a look at the link in the first paragraph of my answer, it leads to the documentation for the class and describes the parameters it takes. The values for these parameters should be listed in your `token.json` file.

Comment: I did not understand the problem and your solution, after print(creds.token_uri) this is the result: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

Comment: Please my update

Comment: Could you change the line `creds.refresh(Request())` in your original code to `creds.refresh(Request)`, that is, pass a request object type, not an instance, to `refresh()` and see if it works?